# Android Open Alert Dialog Box on continuousally tapping on Screen

Tags: android

We have an android app. In the app we have to set Ip Address for that we have an one alert box. But now I have to open alert dialog box when i will tapping on screen 4 to 5 times.

Comment: Please share some code. Also this would be a good read - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Keep a counter in an `int` variable, and each time the screen is tapped, increment the counter. When it becomes 4 or greater, reset it to 0 and open the dialog.

If you want to prevent the dialog from opening a second time, do not reset the counter the first time, and also check for exactly 4 or 5 instead of a "greater than" comparison. Of course that doesn't prevent overflow exploits, so an alternative would be a boolean value storing whether the dialog has previously opened.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pseudo code which gives the gist of the logic.

```
 int counter=0;
    //inside your screen tapping method
    onScreenTapped(){
        //increasing count on each tap
        counter++;
        //checking the number of count
        if (counter==4){
            //call your alert dialog method here
            showAlertDialog();
            //reset your counter to 0
            counter=0;
        }
    }
```